# Android Play Store version code maintenance issue

Tags: android, versioning

I recently splitted my app apk into two version based on the [this multi-versioning guide](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html).
the version code was **8012** for API 8+ and **14012** for API 14+ as document recommended.

But I want to merge these multi apks back to single one because I solve the compatibility issues and suffer to maintain two versions.

In this situation, if I release new single apk as version **8013**, previous **14012** users might not get the update, right? Do I have to publish version code as **14013**? Then, what if I (again) decide to split app into two version? never to use version code **80xx** as document recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I release new single apk as version 8013, previous 14012

You will not be able to release app with lower versionCode that already released build.

Answer (score 0):

I decide to release same files but only to modify manifest in order to maintain separate version code for later use.

so, in my case, simply **8013** for API 8+ and **14013** for API 14+ with only manifest differences.